# Removing very similar Tweets in R

Tags: r, text, twitter

I am preprocessing tweets scraped using Twitter API in R and I have noticed that significant chunk of the tweets are basically duplicates with some minimal variation. In example: "zero knowledge proofs playmajor role in the future of web defi and surveyhwqzunrxnd" and "zero knowledge proofs playmajor role in the future of web defi and surveydupltawvj". There are hundreds of such cases, often there are as much as eight almost identical tweets. How can I drop those too similar tweets? It introduces significant bias into my research, especially given that probably all of them are bot-generated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Does this solve your requirement?

Comment: Hi! Please, give me an hour and I'll try to implement it :) thanks!

Comment: Did you get a chance to implement this solution?

Comment: Hey! I would be glad if you could let me know if my answer helped you or not. I am trying to help other R Users and I'd be happy if users that I am helping acknowledge my effort. If this answer meets your requirement, please consider up voting it and pressing the tick mark on the left so other users are struggling with similar issue do not end up wasting more time. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Sorry for delay. In general it was helpful, cause it worked on my dummy data. However I had problem for applying it in my particular use case. Not sure one, but definitely that's an error on my side; answer is working!

Comment: Please consider upvoting it and clicking on the tick mark on the left side of the post so other community users can benefit from your post and my response. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not that good with NLP but I used the following approach:

- Creating all possible (2 pair) combination of tweets
- Calculating the similarity scores
- Setting a threshold and removing highly similar tweets (i.e. if similarity between tweets is greater than 60% i'll keep only one of them and will remove the other)

```
## Loading the required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(strinr)
library(RecordLinkage)

## Creating Dummy Data
df_tweets = data.frame(RowID = c(1:11),
                       tweets = c("I like this product", 
                                  "Thats awesome",
                                  "Amazing",
                                  "Amazinggg",
                                  "This is cool",
                                  "zero knowledge proofs playmajor role in the future of web defi and surveyhwqzunrxnd",
                                  "zero knowledge proofs playmajor role in the future of web defi and surveydupltawvj",
                                  "Awesome!!",
                                  "Wowwww",
                                  "Simply Amazing",
                                  "Dangggg"))

## Creating 2 pair Combination of all tweets
df1 = data.frame(t(combn(df_tweets$tweets,2)))

## Calculating the similarity scores
df1$similarityscores = levenshteinSim(df1[,1], df1[,2])

## Removing those tweets where the similarity score is greater than 60%
df_tweets_RemovedSimilar = df_tweets %>%
  filter(!(tweets %in% df1[df1$similarityscores>0.6,]$X2))
```

[image]

Comment: This methodology looks correct to me. However, in my lectures, I have heard professors talking about using a distance matrix. I don't know how applicable that method would be for this problem. Overall, I think this should be a good approach to this problem.